# Want to see merge of dictionary in sorted way

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am able to merge two dictionary but want to see dict 2 in continuation with *dict1.*

```py
def Merge(dict1, dict2):
    res={**dict1, **dict2}

    return res

dict1= {'a':3,'b':7,'c':9}
dict2= {'d':7,'e':8}
mergedict = Merge(dict1,dict2)

print(mergedict)
```

**Actual Result** : `{'d': 7, 'a': 3, 'e': 8, 'b': 7, 'c': 9}`

**Expected Result** : `{'a':3, 'b':7, 'c':9, 'd':7, 'e':8}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dict` retain insertion order only from python 3.7. For older versions of python use `OrderedDict`

**On Python 3.7 and above**

```
>>> {**dict1,**dict2}
{'a': 3, 'b': 7, 'c': 9, 'd': 7, 'e': 8}
```

**For older versions**

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dict1 = OrderedDict(sorted({'a':3,'b':7,'c':9}.items()))
>>> dict2 = OrderedDict(sorted({'d':7,'e':8}.items()))      
>>> OrderedDict(dict1,**dict2)
OrderedDict([('a', 3), ('b', 7), ('c', 9), ('d', 7), ('e', 8)])
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine, even if the asker cannot move to Python 3.7+. `collections` contains a lot of very useful tools and should be considered idiomatic.

Comment: Still not getting the expected result. Getting-OrderedDict([('d', 7), ('a', 3), ('e', 8), ('b', 7), ('c', 9)])

Comment: Probably needs to switch from 3.5 to 3.7 now

Comment: @AbhishekBhushan With python 3.5, you have to start with OrderedDict for dict1 and dict2

Answer (score -1):

Update to python greater than 3.7 the output will be your expected result.